# Python add char "\" for no reason

Tags: python, string

I have code where I add a number and then create URL for a request

```
opa_number = '31108100'    
def get_data(opa_number):
        print(opa_number)
        url = "https://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT * FROM opa_properties_public WHERE parcel_number = " \
              + "'" + self.opa_number + "'"
```

[image: Please see image]

When I'm running this code in console line by line it works as it should

When I'm running this code in debugger it gives me
'https://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT * FROM opa_properties_public WHERE parcel_number = \'888020936\''
and add "" around opa_number
My question is why Python is adding this symbol and stop it from doing that

Comment: It's being escaped. The debugger is playing smart and showing you the `repr` of the string, so you could theoretically use it to reconstruct the original perfectly. When you print from a regular program, it uses the `str`, which is the user-friendly representation.

Comment: Okay, and what is your *question*? What do you think should happen instead? Why do you think this is "for no reason"? Hint: what happens if you try to use `'opa_number = '1''` in your source code?

Comment: This is straight SQL-injection, and should be avoided. Run `q=DELETE FROM opa_properties` for example... (doesn't need to be you, anyone could run that)

Comment: Also, if something works, then why do you think it needs changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of trying to display strings as legal Python string literals. The debugger apparently reimplemented string display, and chose to unconditionally use single-quotes around strings it displays (it doesn't seem to rely directly on `str`'s `repr`, which would dynamically select the outer quotation mark to be the opposite of the internal ones if only one is used internally; that's what you'd see when such a string was echoed in the interactive interpreter).

Because it's using outer single-quotes, it has to backslash escape the internal single-quotes to make a legal string literal. The backslashes aren't actually there, your code is behaving as expected.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, I thought it's a bug that causing my program to crash. Now , I found what is really the cause